# Trigger default event on styled select on android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, mobile

I have a custom wrapper on a select box. When I click it I want to display the native select from android. I tried triggering "focus", "click" and "mouseenter" on the hidden select but none of those options worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I created a fiddle after much tinkering and it worked (turns out to be webkit only). If anyone comes up with a better solution, it will be much appreciated.

HTML

```
<button id="clickme" value="click me!">Click me!</button>
<select id="select">
    <option>Default</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
var clickme = jQuery("#clickme"),
    select = jQuery("#select");
clickme.on("mousedown", function (e) {
    proxyMouseEvent(e, select[0]);
});
clickme.on("click", function (e) {
    proxyMouseEvent(e, select[0]);
});
function proxyMouseEvent(event, element) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent(event.type, event.bubbles, event.cancelable, window,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwSvU/8/)

Basically, I'm capturing the event in from the button, copying it and sending it to the select. When the select detects the mousedown event upon itself, it triggers it's default behavior (which in a desktop os is to show a drop down list, whilst in mobile it shows an overlay list)